# Checking if an associated object has failed to save/create

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I smell something wrong here, but am not quite sure what the most *idiomatic* way to solve the problem.

I have a controller for (job)`listings` and it has a method called `apply`.  This method is used when someone has a resume and is clicking to apply for the job associated with the `listing`.

```
def apply
  set_resume
  if @resume.apply_to(@listing)
    redirect_to @listing
  else
    redirect_to @listing, alert: 'Unable to apply for job'
  end
end
```

This calls a method on the `resume` object:

```
def apply_to(listing)
  jobapp = Jobapp.new(resume: self, listing: listing)
  jobapp.save
end
```

Everything above works just fine - it just seems inelegant (and I don't get the errors associated with the `jobapp` object, although that's not vitally important).

If I use the following method in place of the above method:

```
def apply_to(listing)
  Jobapp.create(resume: self, listing: listing)
end
```

The conditional `if @resume.apply_to(@listing)` always returns true, even if the `Jobapp` failed to be created.

What is a cleaner way of achieving this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the current setup, the simplest thing would probably be to raise an exception using [`#save!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save-21):

```
def apply_to(listing)
  jobapp = Jobapp.new(resume: self, listing: listing)
  jobapp.save! # note the bang (!)
end
```

And in the controller

```
def apply
  set_resume
  @resume.apply_to(@listing)
  redirect_to @listing
rescue ActiveRecordError
  redirect_to @listing, alert: 'Unable to apply for job'
end
```

It may be worth the effort to rename your method to `apply_to!` (also with a bang) to make it clear that it can raise an exception.

---

As for why `create` doesn't work, it's not that it returns `true` - it returns the new record (and all objects except nil and false are considered "true"). To check if `create` actually managed to *persist* that record in the database, you can check `record.persisted?`. If true, then it was saved just fine.

So using your `create` version of the method, you could do

```
def apply
  set_resume
  jobapp = @resume.apply_to(@listing)
  if jobapp.persisted?
    redirect_to @listing
  else
    redirect_to @listing, alert: 'Unable to apply for job'
  end
end
```

This would also let you access `jobapp.errors`, if you want.

---

A few other things caught my eye:

1. `set_resume` should probably be in a before-filter. Or be a method that just returns a record, leaving it up to the caller to stick it in an instance variable (or not)
2. I imagine a `jobapp` belongs to a `listing` (and/or a `resume`). If so, it'd be cleaner to build it like so:

   ```
   jobapp = owner.jobapps.new(other: foo)
   ```

Given that it's this simple, though, it might be something you could just do in the controller.

It's never quite clear where a join model like `jobapp` (which I assume is basically a join model) should be created. Should it be in the `Resume` model or in the `Listing` model? Either one makes sense. So the Solomonic solution is do neither (at least for now), and handle it in the controller:

```
def apply
  jobapp = @listing.jobapps.new(resume: @resume)
  if jobapp.save
    redirect_to @listing
  else
    redirect_to @listing, alert: 'Unable to apply for job'
  end
end
```

Lastly, you might want to tweak that error message. It seems a little "blunt" to me. Though it's the server that failed, it sounds as if the user is unable to apply for the job. "Failed to save job application" might be more appropriate

Comment: Your assumptions were correct and you were definitely a step ahead of me with the idea of, ". . . Either one makes sense. So the Solomonic solution is do neither (at least for now), and handle it in the controller. . ." I like this.

Comment: @Ecnalyr Yeah, it's the sort of solution I keep forgetting to use myself, because you always feel it belongs in a model - but it works, and really makes a lot of sense to have it in the controller. And if, some day, you need more logic, you can start by extracting it into a method or a service object.